# Login to remote server with Php and Curl not working

Tags: php, cookies, curl

trying to login to a remote server using curl and php but getting errors about cookies not enabled. Here's my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$url = 'http://uk.songselect.com/account/login/';
$username = '*****';
$password = '******';
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'tmp/cookie.txt');


//run the process and fetch the document
$doc = curl_exec($ch);



// extract __RequestVerificationToken input field
preg_match('#<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"#is',            $doc, $match);

 $token = $match[1];



// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,         '__RequestVerificationToken='.$token.'&UserName='.$username.'&Password='.$password.'');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);



//run the process and fetch the document
$doc = curl_exec($ch);
echo $doc;

//terminate curl process
curl_close($ch);

//print output


echo $token;
```

This is the error I'm getting: 'You need to have cookies enabled in your browser to use the SongSelect site as an authenticated user.'

Any ideas why this is happening?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to init another cUrl channel with cookies saved in tmp/cookie.txt and exec it.

Answer (score 0):

To add cookies to your curl request :

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, uniquefilename );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, uniquefilename );
```

Comment: tried that and it doesn't change anything. still getting the same error